# Pagination within ajax using symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I have a page, `PageA` which has a drop down box. Currently whenever a change is detected, it will take that selected option, send to to another page/action, `PageB` which will have it's respective information pulled out from a database and paginate.

`PageA` has a div which will then load `PageB` using `$("#div_here").load(module/PageB)`;

I've gotten pagination to work stand alone before, however I'm not sure what I should put as my next links for the pagination within PageB.

Any advice would be helpful.

Thanks guys.

Comment: The question is not clearly stated, and thus very confusing

Answer (score 0):

try this it would be helpful hopefully

http://www.solidwebcode.com/web-development/symfony-php/4ajax-pagination/